# Does $e^{AB}=e^{BA}$ imply $AB=BA$?

Tags: matrices, matrix-exponential

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and $B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$. Is it true that $e^{AB}=e^{BA}$ implies $AB=BA$? If not, can you provide a counter example?

Answer (score 7):

Not necessarily. You can find $A$, $B$, $2\times 2$ matrices with real entries such that 
$$AB - BA = \left(\begin{matrix} 0 & - 2 \pi \\
2\pi & 0 \end{matrix} \right)$$

Then 
$$e^{AB-BA} = \left(\begin{matrix} \cos 2\pi & - \sin 2 \pi \\
\sin 2\pi & \cos 2 \pi \end{matrix} \right)= I_2$$ and so $e^{AB} = e^{BA}$ ( cheating a bit here, since we need $AB$, $BA$ commuting, but see details below).

$\bf{Added:}$ Here are details:

Take $$A= \left(\begin{matrix} 1  & 0 \\
0 & -1 \end{matrix} \right)\\
B= \left(\begin{matrix} 0  & -\pi \\
-\pi & 0 \end{matrix} \right)\\
$$

Then 
$$AB = \left(\begin{matrix} 0  & -\pi \\
\pi & 0 \end{matrix} \right)\\
BA= \left(\begin{matrix} 0  & \pi \\
-\pi & 0 \end{matrix} \right)\\
$$

We have $e^{AB} = e^{BA}= -I_2$.

Comment: Can't follow your last step. How do you get the conclusion?

Comment: @velut luna: Ah, use $e^{X-Y} = e^{X} \cdot (e^Y)^{-1}$

Comment: @orangeskid is is true in general? I thought we need some assumption like $X, Y$ commuting? Also, can you tell me how to find matrices $A, B$ with $AB - BA$ like in your answer?

Comment: @Petr Naryshkin: Yes, you are right, only when they commute. I have to check the proof...

Comment: Explicitly, take $A=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{pmatrix}\pi&0\\0&-\pi\end{pmatrix}$. Then $AB$, $BA$ are negatives of each other so they commute.

Comment: @stewbasic: yes, indeed! I noticed your comment after rushing to save the answer. In retrospect, it's easy to see that $e^{AB} = e^{BA}=-I_2$.

Comment: @Petr Naryshkin: the answer was salvageable after all.... added some details

Comment: Thanks! I was really curious to know the answer!